# Nested Tab bar inside Stack Navigator using react navigation and redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I have followed this great [tutorial](https://medium.com/@parkerdan/react-navigation-with-complete-redux-state-management-tab-bar-and-multiple-navigators-ed30a69d9a4d) which is Tab Bar with three tabs using redux. Everything works great. Now I am trying to nest this Tab Bar inside Stack Navigator but I have the following error:

[image]

I am new to Redux and really cannot find where is the problem. Here is my code:

StackNav.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addNavigationHelpers } from 'react-navigation';

import { RootNav } from './../navigationConfiguration';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { navigationState: state.nav };
};

class StackNav extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { dispatch, navigationState } = this.props;
        return (
            <RootNav
                navigation={
                    addNavigationHelpers({
                        dispatch,
                        state: navigationState,
                    })
                }
            />
        );
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(StackNav);
```

StackNav's navigationConfiguration.js

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import TabBarNavigation from './../tabBar/views/TabBarNavigation';
import Welcome from './../../Screens/Register/Welcome.js';

const routeConfiguration = {
    Welcome: { screen: Welcome },
    Home: { screen: TabBarNavigation },
};

const stackNavigatorConfiguration = {
    initialRouteName: 'Welcome',
    headerMode: 'screen',
    navigationOptions: {
        header: { visible: false }
    }
};

export const RootNav = StackNavigator(routeConfiguration, stackNavigatorConfiguration);
```

Reducers

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

// Navigation
import { AppNavigator } from './../stackNav/navigationConfiguration';
import { NavigatorTabOne } from './../tabOne/navigationConfiguration';
import { NavigatorTabTwo } from './../tabTwo/navigationConfiguration';
import { NavigatorTabThree } from './../tabThree/navigationConfiguration';

export default combineReducers({
    nav: (state, action) => AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state),
    tabOne: (state, action) => NavigatorTabOne.router.getStateForAction(action, state),
    tabTwo: (state, action) => NavigatorTabTwo.router.getStateForAction(action, state),
    tabThree: (state, action) => NavigatorTabThree.router.getStateForAction(action, state),
});
```

I also tried with this reducer instead nav: above

```
import { AppNavigator } from './../stackNav/navigationConfiguration';

const initialState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(AppNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Welcome'));

export const navReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);

  return nextState || state;
};
```

Start point of the app:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    Text
} from 'react-native';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import StackNav from './../App/stackNav/views/StackNav';
import store from './store';

Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <StackNav />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => App);
```

I will appreciate any help. Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, you're importing AppNavigator when you shoould be importing { RootNav } in reducer index

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct answer to your question, but I can offer an example of how to nest Tab Navigators in Stack Navigators in this tutorial - https://developerlife.com/2017/04/15/navigation-and-styling-with-react-native/

Here's the JS class (from the tutorial and it's GitHub repo) that sets up the navigators and nesting - https://github.com/r3bl-alliance/react-native-weather/blob/master/app/Router.js

[image: image that shows how the navigators are nested]